# async Module Error Handling , is there a way i can identify which block of callback is throwing error.

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

If we have a function any way we can identify which call back is throwing an error

```
  Async.parallel({
 function one:(){
 },function two(){}
},function(err,results){
//any way we can identify which call back is throwing an error
});
```

It is needed because for some calls i need to show a n error page for some i just need to show the page irrespective of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An error value is returned back from whichever async operation returned an error.  You just need to make sure that each operation returns an indentifiable error value.  If it's an error object (which is recommended), you can add any custom properties you want to it.  Then, in your final error handler, you can look at the properties on the error object and see what properties are on it, what values they have and therefore which path caused the error.

If you want more specific help than that, you will need to show us your actual code for the async operations so we can make more specific code recommendations.

Comment: are you saying that , i define a custom error or give a name to the error . And then identify it ?

Comment: @RohitKatyal - It's explained in my answer.  Just add some identifying property to the error.